# UICollectionView, scrolling to an Item without knowing its NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have a UIcollectionview that shows an array of objects called Items.
At one point in the lifecycle of my app I do need to move the collectionview ( or scroll it ) to a specific Item that I receive Via NSnotification. I do not know the NSIndexPath of that Item but its definitely available in the collectionview. 
I tried

```
  NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:myItem inSection:1];
  [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:myIndexPath  
   atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
                                   animated:NO];
```

But this gives back an arbitrary number and not relevant.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is dataType of myItem, the API expects NSInteger. Is myItem NSInteger?

Comment: myItem is of type Item, which is why I cannot use it in that method, but I have no way of looking that up in a collecionview!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know details of code so i am generalising my answer.

You can have a unique property for myItem say ID.

If you are maintaining an array of items say : myItemArray, and populating collection view in same order then following can work:

```
NSArray* myItemArray; //array used to populate collectionView
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath; //this is what we need to know
int index = 0;

//myItem is object of item type & notifiedItem is notified item
for (Item* myItem in myItemArray) {
    if (myItem.ID == notifiedItem.ID) {
         myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:1];//you got the index path right
        break;
    }
    index++;
}

//use the index path
```

Comment: Well this kind of does the job, I have something along those lines with using isEqual. I tried going through the available methods on uicollectionview but found nothing, still hoping for something more effecient than looping over myArray ( it get be quite large)

Comment: To make it simpler you can have the property of index declared for item and set it while populating UICollectionView, When you will get notification then you can just take the index and get NSIndexPath. No need to iterate on array.